# Save arabic text to mysql using Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

everyone, my app based on Spring MVC and i was trying to persist Arabic text in MySQL (i use JPA) but it's save **????** instead of Arabic characters. I tried to use  this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

but i got error when i tried to save text in Arabian:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xAA\xD8\xB1\xD8\xAD...' for column 'last_name' at row 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the table collection to utf8_general_ci.it should be work..

Answer (score 2):

Hi after a bit of search in the internet I added a couple of lines to my application.properties in order to use UTF-8 encoding and it finally worked. here is the file. don't forget to change the url and password etc.

```
   # DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the   
# #database 
    # connection. In this example we have "netgloo_blog" as database name #and 
    # "root" as username and password.
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newDB?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = somePassword

    # Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in #production)
    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
    spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

    # Show or not log for each sql query
    spring.jpa.show-sql = true

    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8

    # HTTP encoding (HttpEncodingProperties)
    spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
    spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
    spring.http.encoding.force=true

    # Naming strategy
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

    # Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the #prefix is
    # stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

    # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen #database
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true

    server.port=8080
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I checked and discovered that my MySQL was using **utf8mb4** encoding, so I solved problem by configuring MySQL by setting default encoding to  **utf8_unicode** .