# Insert arabic into mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, arabic

I'm trying to insert arabic values into mysql database. my web app is build using hibernate and based on MVC pattern.
I'm asking after that I had tried many things :

**Mysql :**
I have altered datebase, tables and columns to accept `UTF-8.`
So now, I can insert text in arabic using mysql interface.

**TomCat :**
I have added `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.

**JSP :**  I put `<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` in all jsp.

the problem is that I can display arabic text in jsp but I can't insert into database. When I print it, I get `Ù?Ø²Ù?Ù? Ø¹ØªÙ?Ù?Ù?` and I get `??????? ??????` when I print like that `System.out.println(new String(obj.getName().getBytes(), "UTF-8"));`

And when i print `System.out.println(new String("لكل حرف".getBytes(), "UTF-8"));` i get it.

Is it possible that it's due to multiple encoding ?

**EDIT :**

I got it after moving from tomcat 9 to tomcat 8 but I got 
`Ã©` instead of `é`

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424150/save-arabic-text-to-mysql-using-spring-jpa

Comment: i have added `hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
hibernate.connection.encoding.force=true`

Comment: the problem is when the informations are passed from jsp to my server. but i can't see what i did wrong

Comment: and do you have setCharacterEncoding with correct encoding during getting request as first thing what you are doing?

Comment: yes yes , `@Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

      CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
      characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
      characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
      return new Filter[] {characterEncodingFilter};
    }`